# How to fix social media profile URL appears in the end of every WordPress posts' URLs?

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting, nsurlconnection

I am having issue right now regarding my WordPress URL. Not only appears on posts' URL, but also in the main domain. My social media profile URL always appears in the end of every URL of my WordPress site, for example:

```
http://www.seniberpikir.com/id.linkedin.com/in/walterpinem/
```

That is the URL appears on my main domain, and every time I posted an article, the same social media Profile always appears. The example is exactly the same with the above, here is:

```
http://www.seniberpikir.com/mengintegrasikan-google-adsense-dan-google-analytics/id.linkedin.com/in/walterpinem/
```

The "`/id.linkedin.com/in/walterpinem/`" parameter always appears in the end of every URL as the additional URL, and this causes too many 404 error not found for my website, and drains my organic visitors. Please help me to fix this issue. FYI, I haven't installed any new plugins recently, so I thought it didnt cause by a plugin. Thank you very much

Comment: Can you tell what plugins you did installed so far?

Comment: I have done it, I fixed it! Thanks @HashiramaSenju for replying. It is not caused by any plugins, it appeared because there was an error on social media button on my site. And when I changed it to the exact social media URL, it automatically goes to what it should be. Thanks anyway. And btw, I am a fan of Naruto series too :cheers: ;)